# Reduction of queries in ManyToMany field with prefetch_related

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to reduce further the number of queries. I used prefetch_related decreasing the number of queries. I was wondering if it is possible to reduce to one query. Please let me show the code involved:

I have a view with prefetch_related:

```
class BenefitList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BenefitGetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Benefit.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.filter(deleted=False)

        qs=  queryset.prefetch_related('nearest_first_nations__reserve_id')
    
        return qs
```

I have the models used by the serializers. In here, it is important to notice the hybrid property name which I want to display along with reserve_id and reserve_distance:

benefit.py:

```
class IndianReserveBandDistance(models.Model):
    reserve_id = models.ForeignKey(IndianReserveBandName,
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                   db_column="reserve_id",
                                   null=True)
    reserve_distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=4, blank=False, null=False)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.reserve_id.name
        
class Benefit(models.Model):
    banefit_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    nearest_first_nations = models.ManyToManyField(IndianReserveBandDistance,
                                                   db_column="nearest_first_nations",
                                                   blank=True,
                                                   null=True)
```

Name field is obtained in the model IndianReserveBandName.

indian_reserve_band_name.py:

```
class IndianReserveBandName(models.Model):
    ID_FIELD = 'CLAB_ID'
    NAME_FIELD = 'BAND_NAME'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    band_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Then, the main serializer using BenefitIndianReserveBandSerializer to obtain the fields reserve_id, reserve_distance and name:

get.py:
class BenefitGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
nearest_first_nations = BenefitIndianReserveBandSerializer(many=True)

The serializer to obtain the mentioned fields:
distance.py:

```
class BenefitIndianReserveBandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IndianReserveBandDistance
        fields = ('reserve_id', 'reserve_distance', 'name')
```

The above is resulting in two queries which I would like to be one:

```
SELECT ("benefit_nearest_first_nations"."benefit_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_benefit_id",
       "indianreservebanddistance"."id",
       "indianreservebanddistance"."reserve_id",
       "indianreservebanddistance"."reserve_distance"
  FROM "indianreservebanddistance"
 INNER JOIN "benefit_nearest_first_nations"
    ON ("indianreservebanddistance"."id" = "benefit_nearest_first_nations"."indianreservebanddistance_id")
 WHERE "benefit_nearest_first_nations"."benefit_id" IN (1, 2)
 
 
 SELECT "indianreservebandname"."id",
       "indianreservebandname"."name"
  FROM "indianreservebandname"
 WHERE "indianreservebandname"."id" IN (678, 140, 627, 660, 214, 607)
 ORDER BY "indianreservebandname"."id" ASC
```

I am expecting the following query:

```
SELECT ("benefit_nearest_first_nations"."benefit_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_benefit_id",
       "indianreservebanddistance"."id",
       "indianreservebanddistance"."reserve_id",
       "indianreservebanddistance"."reserve_distance",
       "indianreservebandname"."name"
  FROM "indianreservebanddistance"
 INNER JOIN "benefit_nearest_first_nations"
    ON ("indianreservebanddistance"."id" = "benefit_nearest_first_nations"."indianreservebanddistance_id")
 inner JOIN  "indianreservebandname"
    on ("indianreservebandname"."id" = "indianreservebanddistance"."reserve_id")
 WHERE "benefit_nearest_first_nations"."benefit_id" IN (1, 2)
```

Would you know if it is possible to get just one query? Am I missing something which is stopping Django to create just one query?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `.prefetch_related` always works with two queries. Using a single one, would result in *a lot* of data duplication, and could "blow up" the memory.

Comment: `Would you know if it is possible to get just one query?` i think it is possible if you change your database a bit, is it possible in your case to change db? You may change `nearest_first_nations = models.ManyToManyField(
        IndianReserveBandDistance,
        through='BenefitIndianReserveBand')` it will create custom middle table with which you could use select_related

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something which is stopping Django to create just one query?

**Yes**. The behavior of using two queries is on deliberately. It prevents introducing *data duplication*, where the same values for the same columns are repeated *a lot*. This can blow up memory usage (both at the database side and the Django/Python side), and render the system unresponsive. In fact, it can even result in the *out of memory (OOM) manager* killing the web application, the database, or another application.